# Importing npm packages in Nativescript Playground

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to learn `nativescript-vue` where I'm using the Nativescript's Playground to tryout my sample codes. I'm trying to use `nativescript-localstorage` package so that I can store some of  the information into local storage:

Whenever I'm trying to save project it is giving use compilation error

[image: Error in importing]

and following is the error:

> An error occurred while transpiling nativescript-localstorage/localstorage.js.
>   unknown: We found a path that isn't a NodePath instance. Possiblly due to bad serialisation.

I followed the tutorials and added the package as it was instructed my code looks like:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import localStorage from 'nativescript-localstorage';
import userStore from './user-store';

//For local storage of vuex tools
const NSVuexPersistent = store => {
 // Init hook.
 let storageStr = localStorage.getItem('ns-vuex-persistent');
 if (storageStr) {
  store.replaceState(JSON.parse(storageStr))
 }
 store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  // Subscribe hook.
  localStorage.setItem('ns-vuex-persistent', JSON.stringify(state));
 })
};

Vue.use(Vuex);

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        userStore
    },
    strict: debug,
    plugins: [NSVuexPersistent]
})
```

Since the project is not getting saved so I've not shared the link. Help me out with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nativescript-vue` is packaged within the Preview APK, so it can be imported as

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
```

But `nativescript-localstorage` is something you have installed in your project, so while at Playground you should use relative path to import the module, something like

```
import * as localStorage from "../nativescript-localstorage"

// Or

const localStorage = require("../nativescript-localstorage");
```

You can use `import name from "package"` only when the package has marked something as default in its exports, the syntax is commonly used in ES6 & Vue plugins. `nativescript-localstorage` has not exported anything as default.

Comment: I can't get this working for module "nativescript-local-notification", I get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'LifecycleCallbacks' of undefined"

Comment: Playground has limitations. You can not use packages those internally use native libraries. FYI, nativescript-local-notification dependencies written in native code.

Comment: what can I use for notifications in playground?

Comment: As I said, Playground has its limitation. It can only be used like JSBin or Stackblitz, to learn, run quick samples and share code. I would recommend you to build projects locally for stuffs like notification and all OR if you still want to use Playground, you can directly access the native apis to send notifications.